# Dataframe: Computed row based on cell above and cell on the left

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a bunch of integer values. I then compute the column totals and append it as a new row to the dataframe. So far so good.

Now I want to append another computed row where the value of each cell is the sum of cell above and the cell on the left. You can see what I mean below:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
|250000 |0      |145000 |145000 |220000 |165000 |145000 |145000  |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
|250000 |250000 |395000 |540000 |760000 |925000 |1070000|1215000 |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with select last row (total row) by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9],
         'D':[1,3,5],
         'E':[5,3,6],
})

df.loc['sum'] = df.sum()
df.loc['cumsum'] = df.iloc[-1].cumsum()

#if need only cumsum row
#df.loc['cumsum'] = df.sum().cumsum()
print (df)
         B   C   D   E
0        4   7   1   5
1        5   8   3   3
2        4   9   5   6
sum     13  24   9  14
cumsum  13  37  46  60
```

Comment: @SilentUser - You are welcome! Small friend advice - [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) for prevent downvotes

Comment: I have been wondering why my question got 3 downvotes. Thank you for the link and making me aware. I wish others had done so too before down voting. I will remove the image.