# How to access newly added (generated) row in a dataframe by index name?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of integers to which I add 2 more generated rows called 'sum' and 'cumsum' (cumulative sum) based on this answer:
[Dataframe: Computed row based on cell above and cell on the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592678/dataframe-computed-row-based-on-cell-above-and-cell-on-the-left)

Now when I access the newly added row by its index like so:

```
myMatrix.iloc['sum']['January']
```

I get the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer object' has no attribute 'sum'
```

So I tried resetting the index to ensure 'sum' and 'cumsum' are added to the index.

> myMatrix.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

But I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `myMatrix.loc`, not `iloc`

Comment: `myMatrix.loc['sum','January']`

Comment: Yes, that works. Also I realized I shouldn't do a reset index as it converts 'sum' and 'cumsum' to integer indices. Please addf ypur response as answer (rather than comment) so that I can ac cept the answer.